# Could we have a silly season - again?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, asking-questions, community

Last Summer, [the idea was floated around](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3185/should-we-have-a-silly-season) that we have a silly season, were people could ask fun or humorous questions?

Can we try that this year?

Comment: Yes, please. Let's do that.

Comment: @JosephWeissman Here's my contribution: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/43673/does-being-a-moral-atheist-require-being-a-vegetarian

Comment: Pythagoras approves :)

Comment: We may want a note or disclaimer on these, just to ensure the satire is somewhat clear

Comment: @JosephWeissman I tagged mine as "Summer-Silly" and stated that the post was semi-serious.

Comment: Consider to improve (or basically, edit) the tag excerpt (and wiki if possible) to provide some insight regarding that tag. Otherwise, people would be confused about the meaning of that tag.